# On Tabitem selection, Style is not performing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created style for Tab Control and TabItem in xaml file.

When TabControl is loading first time on window , its applying style as it wanted. 
But when I am selecting another tabItem, its not performing IsSelection property style.

> On selection 
>   : Path Stroke="blue" and background of Bd = "yellow".

Please help me to sort this issue.

Thank you in advance.

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,4,4,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteColorBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"/>

        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0" Width="480"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" 
                            CornerRadius="0,5,5,5" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteColorBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MediumTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="105px"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" >
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Height="32" Focusable="False">
                        <Path x:Name="Bd" Fill="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Blue" Data="M32.112576,21.370581 C32.11147,19.654586 32.018481,10.83178 32.130291,
                          2.8647957 32.168301,0.15634975 32.890504,-0.063229885 33.673263,-0.10401306 33.673263,-0.10401306 46.603605,-0.10439528 46.603605,-0.10439528 48.464699,-0.081679943 48.572192,13.549447 50.678186,21.503142" Stretch="Fill" Width="105px" Cursor="Hand" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Content" Padding="1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="95" Foreground="{DynamicResource BlackColorBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="center"
                               Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" ToolTip="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" TargetName="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem},Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Header}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource UnSelectedBrush}"/>
                            <!--<Setter Property="TextTrimming" TargetName="Content" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>-->
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteColorBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-1" TargetName="Bd"/>

                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Opacity" Value="0.6"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="Bd" Value="Hand" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-3" TargetName="Bd"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bd" Value="Yellow"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="2"/>
                            <!--<Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" TargetName="Content" Value="DemiBold"/>-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1" TargetName="Bd"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource UnSelectedItemBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="Bd" Value="Hand"/>
                            <!--<Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" TargetName="Content" Value="DemiBold"/>-->
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Content" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteColorBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="Bd" Value="Hand"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-3" TargetName="Bd"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bd" Value="Yellow"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: So, you want to achieve: when the item is selected, the Stroke to be "blue" and the background to be "yellow"?

Comment: Yes, On selection Trigger is not performing  @Iron

Comment: How is your `NormalBrush`?

Comment: @iron Its a LightGray color

Comment: In the trigger `Trigger Property="IsSelected"`, you has set the `Stroke`  to be `Yellow` and the `Fill (Background)` to be `NormalBrush`, not "blue" and "yellow".

Comment: @Iron.. I have  all these things.But it didn't work

Comment: Try the code in my answer, do you want to add other any other effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" TargetName="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem},Mode=FindAncestor},Path=Header}"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource UnSelectedBrush}"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="TextTrimming" TargetName="Content" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteColorBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-1" TargetName="Bd"/>

    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <!--<Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Opacity" Value="0.6"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="Bd" Value="Hand" />
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-3" TargetName="Bd"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bd" Value="Yellow"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="2"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" TargetName="Content" Value="DemiBold"/>-->
    </Trigger>
    <!--<MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1" TargetName="Bd"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource UnSelectedItemBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="Bd" Value="Hand"/>
        --><!--<Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" TargetName="Content" Value="DemiBold"/>--><!--
    </MultiTrigger>-->
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="Content" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteColorBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" TargetName="Bd" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-3" TargetName="Bd"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bd" Value="Yellow"/>-->
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="2"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: No, Its not working. While I am selecting another tab item, its not triggering "IsSelection" Property.

Comment: What's `IsSelection` property?

Comment: sorry IsSelected property where i am defining background and stroke value

Comment: Can you show the code that binding the `TabItem` and `IsSelected`?

Comment: i found my mistake. I was binding wrongly. I have correct it. Thanks for the guidance.